# Mount specific fstab entry

Tags: mount, fstab

Sometimes you need to disconnect and reconnect mounts that have gone bad and don't want to disconnect + reconnect the entire list of fstab entries.

Is this possible without having to basically rerun the full underlying mount command that fstab abstracts away? Something like:

```
mount /Videos
```

where fstab contains:

```
//admin@192.168.1.4/Videos$ /Videos smbfs nodev,nosuid,auto
```

I'd rather not copy and paste the entire fstab entry and modify it to use the `mount -o syntax`

Comment: It's exactly how fstab works: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html

Comment: I know that. My question is does the "mount -a" shortcut have some kind of filter that can do the messy stuff for you.

Comment: What does you question have to do with `mount -a`? What "filter"/"messy stuff"?

Comment: If I haven't made it clear by what I've written in the question then no amount of further explaining will either. But thanks for the reply.

Comment: `umount /Videos` and `mount /Videos` will work, and the latter will use the source, type and options in `//admin@192.168.1.4/Videos$ /Videos smbfs nodev,nosuid,auto`, if that's what you want to know.

Comment: You're right! I'm not sure why I never tried this but yes that works. I had assumed it wouldn't be able to distinguish between a mount that does and doesn't read fstab but it behaves exactly as I wanted. If you paste your comment in the answers section i'll mark it as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(Thanks to Tan for the answer)

`umount /Videos` and `mount /Videos` will work, and the latter will use the source, type and options in `//admin@192.168.1.4/Videos$ /Videos smbfs nodev,nosuid,auto` that is specified in `fstab`.

Side-note: I don’t bother with `/etc/fstab` anymore. I use `/etc/auto.direct`.